# Modifying parameters as part of a multimethod

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

What's the idiomatic way to write a multimethod that modifies the incoming arguments as part of it's dispatch?

In this case, I want to drop one of the arguments:

```
(defmulti do-update ???)

(defmethod do-update :set-cursor [state x y]
  (assoc state :cursor [x y]))

(defn post [action & args]
  (swap! some-state do-update action args))

(post :set-cursor 0 0)
```

The `dispatch-fn` here would be responsible for reading the `action` keyword *and* forwarding `(cons state args)` on as arguments for the methods.

An alternative to this approach would be creating a dispatch map.

```
(defn set-cursor [state x y])

(def handlers
  {:set-cursor set-cursor})

(defn dispatch [action & args]
  (let [handler (action handlers)]
    (apply swap! some-state handler args)))
```

But it would be nice to automatically register those handlers against their corresponding action, without the map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is part of the design of multimethods that the methods receive the same arguments as the dispatch function. If the methods are not interested in certain arguments that are only used for dispatch, then it is perfectly fine – and not at all unusual – to ignore them in method implementations:

```
(def some-state (atom {:cursor [-1 -1]}))

(defmulti do-update
  (fn [state action x y]
    action))

;; ignoring the action argument here:
(defmethod do-update :set-cursor [state _ x y]
  (assoc state :cursor [x y]))

;; added apply here to avoid ArityException in the call to do-update:
(defn post [action & args]
  (apply swap! some-state do-update action args))

(post :set-cursor 0 0)

@some-state
;= {:cursor [0 0]}
```

Note that the dispatch argument comes second here to facilitate the use of `do-update` with `swap!`.

Comment: I'd argue that the use of `_`, along with the arrangement Michał illustrates here is the "normal" way to approach this problem, and as well is the most readily understood.

Answer (score 1):

You can't ask the method directly which input to the dispatch function caused it to choose to call this method, which is ok because the dispatch methods are just functions!

You can call the dispatch function again from within the method it dispatched to. So long as your dispatch function is a pure function this will be solid. If not ...

so if you define yoru dipatch function `???` as this (yes ??? is a valid function name)

```
user=> (defn ??? [x] (inc x))
#'user/???
```

and your multimethod like this:

```
user=> (defmulti foo ???)
```

and then call the dispatch function again in the method:

```
 (defmethod foo 1 [x] 
    (str "I was dispatched from " x 
         " and i will use " (??? x) 
         " to do my good work"))
```

you can reconstruct the actions of the dispatch function without having to maintain an independent function/map/thing.

```
user=> (foo 0)
"I was dispatched from 0 and i will use 1 to do my good work"
```

Answer (score 1):

While the core language doesn't support this, you could employ some "rewriting" macros to layer on your desired semantics:

```
(defmacro defupdatemulti [name] 
  `(defmulti ~name (fn [state# action# & args#] action#)))

(defmacro defupdatemethod [name action [state & args] & body] 
  `(defmethod ~name ~action 
    [~state _# [~@args]] 
    ~@body))
```

And to use this:

```
(defupdatemulti do-update)

(defupdatemethod do-update :set-cursor [state x y] 
  (assoc state :cursor [x y]))
```

With this in place

```
(def some-state (atom {}))

(defn post [action & args]
  (swap! some-state do-update action args))

(post :set-cursor 0 0)
```

yields the following:

```
{:cursor [0 0]}
```

Note: While the above works, it is certainly not idiomatic.